# Parse Bytes from SQL Bytestring after Substring occured in Python

Tags: python, sql, string, utf-8, byte

I have a bytestream coming from an SQL Dump that contains a password hash (non utf-8 characters)
e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (1,'user','[password hash in bytes]', ...);
```

Now i want to extract the raw bytes "[password hash in bytes]" in a byte object using Python.
I thought about something like splitting by ',' but if i try to decode the bytes using .decode('utf-8') I obviously get a decode error:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 45: invalid start byte`

Is there any elegant way how I can extract the bytes from that stream?

Comment: You can split bytestrings with `.split(b",")` without converting to str at all.

Comment: @SuperStormer that actually solved my problem, thank you! i assumed that i can only split after converting to string

Comment: Show an example of the actual string you have.  Is it a bytes string representation `"b'\xnn\xnn'"` or an actual byte string `b'\xnn\xnn'`?

Answer (score 0):

If the data of the password hash isn't encoded, then decoding it is impossible. You mention trying to decode your data, but you haven't shown us your attempt at doing so. If I'm understanding your issue correctly, it sounds like you don't actually need to do any work - the password hash you have should stay as a `bytes` object in memory when you read it from your database.

Comment: I don't want to decode the password hash, I want to extract the password hash bytes from the surrounding sql ascii characters

Comment: @Clemens I'm not sure what you mean by "extract the password hash bytes." From the basic SQL INSERT statement you wrote, it looks like the hash is already separated. Do you have any examples you can show us? We don't have a lot of information to go off of to help you right now.

Comment: the SQL INSERT in my original post is an example line. Yes the hash is separated (by ',') but if i want to split that line by ',' e.g. by using line.decode('utf-8').split(',) I get the mentioned error since line contains non utf-8 chars (the password). So my goal is to have [password hash in bytes] in one separate bytes object without the sql stuff surrounding it